Planner create API with Group Id is not working in Microsoft Graph
I am creating a Planner with Planner create API. For business reason I also have to create a new group and create the planner under the new group. It was working fine until the new Planner update. Now even though I am supplying the groupId, the planner does not create under it and the group members can not access it. Is there any work around for this?
Here is how I am creating a planner,
PlannerPlan requestBody = new()

{

Container = new PlannerPlanContainer

{

Url = $"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/{groupId}",

},

Title = title,

};

var result = await _graphServiceClient.Planner.Plans.PostAsync(requestBody);

And here is how I am creating the group,
Group requestBody = new Group
{
    Description = name,
    DisplayName = name,
    GroupTypes = new List<string>
    {
    },
    MailEnabled = false,
    MailNickname = {nickName},
    SecurityEnabled = true,
    AdditionalData = new Dictionary<string, object>
    {
        {
            "owners@odata.bind" , new List<string>
            {
                $"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{ownerId}",
            }
        },
        {
            "members@odata.bind" , new List<string>
            {
                $"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{ownerId}",
            }
        },
    },

};

var response =await _graphServiceClient.Groups.PostAsync(requestBody);


According to the context, if the owner of the Planner is not a member of the Microsoft 365 group associated with the team, the Planner API may not trigger the plan creation successfully.
To resolve this, ensure that the user attempting to create the Planner is a member of the Microsoft 365 group. You can add the user as a member of the group, which should allow the Planner API to function correctly.

The planner is being created successfully. Just not under the specified group or any other group for that matter. When I try to share the planner, it tells me to create a group or associate with other groups. What I want to know why it is not creating under the specified group? as for the group, the user is already the owner and member of that group.

Is the Group M365 or security?

As I am able to get the GroupID when fetched the plan. And the group ID will be present in the owner section while creating like this

Yes, I am also getting the group id as owner. I have added the group creation code also with the question. But can you tell me how can I know what type of group it really is?

In the Azure Portal check here in groups blade

So the groups are created as security type. I'll try with disabling the SecurityEnabled while creating group.

Yes you have to create M365 group and let me know if it works

@Rukmini, it works with the M365 type group. Thanks so much for your help.

Glad to know it works. Will post the answer in sometime:)


Note that: You cannot create a Planner plan directly with a security group. Planner is designed to work with Microsoft 365 Groups, not security groups.


Planner is integrated into Microsoft 365 Groups, and each group automatically gets a Planner plan that can be used for task management.
A Microsoft 365 Group is a collaborative workspace where you can manage resources like Outlook, Teams, OneDrive, SharePoint, and Planner.

Hence to resolve the issue, make sure to create group as Microsoft 365:
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups
Content-type: application/json

{
  "description": "Test",
  "displayName": "Test",
  "groupTypes": [
    "Unified"
  ],
  "mailEnabled": true,
  "mailNickname": "Test",
  "securityEnabled": false
}



To create Microsoft 365 group via code check the below:
var requestBody = new Group
{
    Description = "Test",
    DisplayName = "Test",
    GroupTypes = new List<string>
    {
        "Unified",
    },
    MailEnabled = true,
    MailNickname = "Test",
    SecurityEnabled = false,
};

var result = await graphClient.Groups.PostAsync(requestBody);

Now create the planner by using below query:
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/planner/plans

{

"container": {
"url": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/M365GroupID"
},
"title": "ruk"
}


Code:
var requestBody = new PlannerPlan
{
    Container = new PlannerPlanContainer
    {
        Url = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/M365GroupID",
    },
    Title = "title-value",
};
var result = await graphClient.Planner.Plans.PostAsync(requestBody);

Reference:
Create plannerPlan - Microsoft Graph v1.0 | Microsoft
